# Start of the Week from SQL Developer and CMD is different

Tags: cmd, toad

I have been executing a SQL query to give me previous weeks transactions from TOAD with condition as TransDate between trunc(sysdate,'Day')-7 and trunc(sysdate,'Day')-(1/24/60/60). This would consider the week starting from Monday to Sunday. This has been working fine for our team.

I am now running the SQL file through CMD batch file but its considering the week from Sunday to Saturday. This is not in sync with the SQL file when executed in TOAD or SQL Developer. Please can someone help me how to fix this issue?

Thanks
Yashodhan

Comment: in TOAD: select trunc(sysdate,'Day')-7 from dual; gives 17th July'17 (start of prev. week is considered as Monday).

Comment: However when executing this code in CMD: it gives 16th July'17 (Start of prev. week is considered as Sunday)